# Design of PrimeFaces web application

Tags: jsf, architecture, user-interface, primefaces

First of all, I am aware that this question might be considered off-topic with respect to StackOverflow. In case, please advise where it could fit better inside StackExchange sites.

I need to develop a simple but complete User Interface for the following (simple) situation: handling the attendances of a number of users to a number of events. The target user of this app is a superuser, i.e. a person who need to monitor and count how many events has taken part each user, and how many users have taken part to an event. The superuser should be able to do any kind of CRUD operations on users, events, attendances.

The db structure is composed of the tables: **user, event, attendance**.

**User** has a `OneToMany` relationship with **attendance**: one user is linked to many attendances.

**Event** has a `OneToMany` relationship with **attendance**.

The layout I have thought is the following (using PrimeFaces widgets): a TabView with 2 Tabs: Users and Events. Each tab shows all records of its type, through `DataTables` with LazyLoading, filtering and sorting on each column.

Each DataTable has additional columns with buttons for Edit-Delete operations. Moreover, an additional column in the User table contains a "View Events" button for viewing the events related to that user. In a specular way, a "View Users" button is present in the Events table.

The "View Events" button opens a modal Dialog that contains another DataTable with the events related to the user.

**Here comes the question**: what's a reasonable way of letting the superuser update this list of events related to the selected user? Should I show all events, including the ones not related, with a column with radio buttons showing the relation? Or should I show only the related events? How will the superuser add new related events? Do I need another DataTable showing the not-yet-related events? Or should I use a PickList? If using a PickList, what happens when the list is long? I don't see pagination or filtering features in PickList component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces `pickList` adds `scroll` if it doesn't fit inside the `parent component`. But it is not efficient to use for large datasets. Use `dataTables` instead. But @Namphibian already said this.

Now to the **design**:

Having `Users` and `Events` in separated `tabs` is good. If I were you I would put 3 `dataTables` inside each tab, e.g. for `User` tab I would have these:

- **All Users**
- **Events related** to particular `User`
- **All Events**

Only **All Users** `dataTable`(with `multiselection`) would be visible on the initial open of the tab.

This `table` would have controll `buttons` in `footer` which will manage showing of another 2 `tables`, e.g.: "***RelatedEvents***","***AssignToEvent***" and "***AddUser***" `buttons`.

After clicking on "***RelatedEvents***" the **Related Events** `dataTable` would be shown (e.g. handle it with `jQuery`). 
In this `table` would be all `Events` related to the selected `User` from the **All Users** table. Here you can manage "***Unassigning***" of the `User` from the event, "***Updating***" of particular `Event` and also of course "***Hiding***" this `table` (jQuery again).

After clicking on "***AssignToEvent***" the **All Events** `dataTable` would be shown (jQuery).
In this `table` would be all existing `Events`. Here you would select particular `Event` and then "***Confirm assigning***" of selected `Users` from **All Users** to selected `Event`. It would also contain "***Hide***" button.

Similar approach for `Event` tab. Since dataTable has many advantages like filtering, sorting, highliting of rows, etc. imo it's the best choice.

This way you will be able to let superUser to browse through all `Users` and edit them without having all `tables` visible, but also letting him manage everything within 2 clicks. (same for Event)

These are just my thoughts. Maybe it will inspire you somehow.

Comment: Sure, your thoughts are extremely useful. I am thinking at something very similar

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule of thumb I would apply is that for longer lists the datatable is much easier to use. You can apply filters and sorting to the tables. Picklist are generally better suited for smaller lists.

Grab a pen and papper sketch out the layouts you are thinking about. I find this is a quick way to review different layout ideas and can help to eliminate problematic designs quickly.